# Volume charge density of charged cloud

Tags: electric-fields, charge, electrical-engineering

Following data is given (exact word-by-word translation into English): 600 meters above surface of the sea, there is a charged cloud of thickness 200 meters which produces electric field $ E = 16000 \frac{V}{m} $ (directed perpendicular to the sea surface). Compute volume charge density inside the cloud.

**My attempt at finding solution:** electric field divergence theorem states that $$ \int Eds = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} $$ From here, computing *surface charge density* yields simple formula

$$ \sigma = \varepsilon_0 E $$

Now, apparently there must be a connection between surface and volume charge density which I'm not aware of. Solution should be $ \rho = 708 \cdot10^{-12} \frac{C}{m^3} $

Comment: Thickness is given as 200 meters.

Comment: Thickness of the cloud, yes. But it's only one dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're cloud is infinite and uniformly charged with a volume charge density $\rho$ and no surface charge density. Using Gauss's theorem, you can show that, outside the cloud, $E = \frac{\rho w}{2\epsilon_0}$ where $w$ is the width of the cloud. Then, you have

$$ \rho = \frac{2E\epsilon_0}{w}$$